# Disable log messages about warnings for org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers in Kafka-Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, apache-kafka-connect

My goal is to make log format in kafka-connect as json, but the following log messages are always not json and cannot be disabled:

```
Feb 10, 2020 4:36:03 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource will be ignored. 
Feb 10, 2020 4:36:03 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource will be ignored. 
Feb 10, 2020 4:36:03 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource will be ignored. 
Feb 10, 2020 4:36:05 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.
```

I know those are warings, so my goal is to either avoid those to show up, or make it in json. Neither work though.

I tried the following setup:

```
<logger name="org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers" additivity="true" level="ERROR" />
```

Those log messages still appear. Any suggestion?

I can use either logback or log4j. I currently use logback but using log4j is not a problem.

**UPDATE**

I switch to log4j

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig=ERROR
```

Logs are in json format except for the WARNINGS are still there even if I set
`log4j.logger.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Provider=ERROR`

Comment: Kafka uses log4j.properties, not XML, so where did you add that?

Comment: I have this in my Dockerfile
`CMD ["-c", "envsubst < connect-kafka.template.properties > connect-kafka.properties && java ${EXTRA_ARGS} ${DOCKER_JAVA_OPTS} -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:logback.xml -cp 'libs/*' org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed connect-kafka.properties "]`

Comment: Are you using the Confluent images? That's not the right command to start connect server. Also, I'd suggest making an external script if you're gonna put that much in the CMD... And why logback anyway? Where are you adding any logback jar files?

Comment: I build image from apache kafka. I updated the post with log4j.

Comment: Why build images for services that already exist? Can you show the whole dockerfile?

Comment: it's build by mvn so plugins can be added via mvn. the docker-compose file is here https://github.com/HungUnicorn/kafka-connect-from-mvn

Comment: You could add plugins with zip files and Confluent Hub command as well. There's a Kafka Connect maven plugin for that

Answer (score 3):

That log message is being logged using the JDK built-in logger (java.util.logging), not SLF4J or log4J:

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/faa809da43538ce31076b50f969b4bd64caa5ac9/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/Providers.java#L514

You need to edit the default JVM logging.properties file or create a custom one and reference it with JVM option *-Djava.util.logging.config.file* in order to set the log level of *org.glassfish.jersey.internal* to SEVERE.

Logging in Java is complicated and messy.  You end up having to know all of the different logging products and often they are mixed together in the same project.

Example logging.properties file:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

org.glassfish.jersey.internal.level = SEVERE
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan commented, to suppress or change those logs, you have to modify the `logging.properties` file.
If you want to modify the default file in the **Kafka Connect Docker image**, it is located in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre/conf/logging.properties`

Answer (score 0):

> WARNINGS are still there even if I set log4j.logger.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Provider=ERROR

The class is **Providers**, with an s

Personally, I'd suggest

```
log4j.logger.org.glassfish.jersey.internal=OFF
```

Comment: hmm warnings are still there after this change. I also found similar warnings in `confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.4.0` `Feb 13, 2020 10:15:47 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime WARNING: A provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SchemasResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SchemasResource will be ignored.`

Comment: I'm not sure which class actually prints the lines. Are you sure that file is overwritten in the container?

Comment: yep, because the log format becomes json, and other log level configs work

Comment: Where do you put 'log4j.logger.org.glassfish.jersey.internal=OFF'?

Comment: @chzbrgla in  `log4j.properties` file. I don't know how you run Kafka. Use `find` command to search for it or `ps aux | grep Kafka | grep log4j`